# How to change default float printing format in python?

Tags: format

Don't want to specify format each time in print statement, like

```
for item in mylist:
    print '%0.2f' % item,
```

Comment: create a function that put the result in the format you want, then just use this function when you need.

Answer (score 0):

An intuitive method that came to my mind consists in creating a function that does that:

```
def format_float(float_value):
    return '%0.2f' % float_value
```

Then you can use it everywhere you need it, such as in your example:

```
for item in mylist:
    print format_float(item)
```

Or you can embed the `print` statement within `format_float()` function directly:

```
def format_float(float_value):
    print '%0.2f' % float_value
```

This you do not need to code print when looping the list:

```
for item in mylist:
    format_float(item)
```